# need help finding the line numbers which its members sum is the biggest in matrix

Tags: java, recursion

i got this problem where i need to return the line which its members bring the biggest sum in matrix, the problem needs to be with recursive methods ( no loops )
i started firstly by finding the biggest sum, but i dont know how to proceed further, please help me

```
public class MatrixLen {

    private int [][] _mat;
    public MatrixLen(int sizeRow, int sizeCol)
    {
    _mat = new int[sizeRow][sizeCol];
    Random generator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i< sizeRow; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<sizeCol; j++){
            _mat[i][j] = generator.nextInt(20) - 10;
            System.out.print(_mat[i][j]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
    private int SumRow(int i){
        return SumRow(i,0);
    }
    private int SumRow(int i, int j){
        if(j>=_mat[i].length) return 0;
        return _mat[i][j] + SumRow(i, j+1);
    }
    public int maxRow(){
        if(_mat.length==0) return -1;
        return maxRow(0);
    }
    private int maxRow(int i){
        if (i == _mat.length - 1) return SumRow(i); //end case - last row
        int max = maxRow (i + 1);
        int thisRow = SumRow(i);
        return thisRow > max ? thisRow : max;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks closed enough to what you need, just return the index of the max row in your method `maxRow`, instead of the sum `sumRow(i)`. Cheers.

Comment: i can return the index of the line only in cases that the row is bigger then max , dont know how to show the index of max

Comment: Something like `return thisRow > sumRow(index_max) ? i : index_max`? (where of course `index_max = maxRow(i+1)`). Anyway, you've got already an answer which is also valid, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class holding the index of the current row as well as the sum. E.g.

```
public class IndexSum {
    int index;
    int sum;

    public IndexSum(int index, int sum) {
        this.index = index;
        this.sum = sum;
    }
}
```

Then in `MatrixLen` modify `maxRow` methods to get as argument and also return a `IndexSum` object. This way, during recursion, you keep track of the sum of a row to compare with other rows, but also of the index of this row.

```
public IndexSum maxRow() {
    if (_mat.length == 0) return null;
    return maxRow(new IndexSum(0, SumRow(0)));
}

private IndexSum maxRow(IndexSum thisRow) {
    if (thisRow.index == _mat.length - 1) return thisRow; //end case - last row
    IndexSum nextRow = maxRow(new IndexSum(thisRow.index + 1 , SumRow(thisRow.index + 1)));
    return thisRow.sum > nextRow.sum ? thisRow : nextRow;
}
```

Comment: no i cant change the return type of maxRow, the least i can do is to add another method

Answer (score 0):

Are member fields accepted ?

```
int index = -1;

private int maxRow(int i) {
    if (i == _mat.length - 1) {
        index = i;
        return SumRow(i); // end case - last row
    }

    int max = maxRow(i + 1);
    int thisRow = SumRow(i);

    if (thisRow > max) {
        index = i;
    }

    if (i == 0) {
        return index;
    }

    return thisRow > max ? thisRow : max;
}
```